# Could not connect iphone device to the XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, macos

I have updated my iPhone4's OS to iOS7. But I have XCode 4.5.1. So when I connect my iphone to XCode in Organizer it says to update the XCode. But very strange thing that some times it suddenly worked and I have successfully debugged. I tried to not down the trick but could not find. It happened many times with me when my device with iOS7 has been connected with XCode 4.5.1. Do anyone knows the trick? So I can be able to connect device regularly. Xcode 5 is not working on my Mac as I have OS 10.7.5 and it is not being updated ...it shows your software is already up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update you OS X (to Mountain Lion) and Xcode (to Xcode 5) in irder to use iOS 7.

Comment: I already told you that when I try to update it shows your software is already up to date. My OS is 10.7.5. Could you tell me steps to update?..Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Download OS X Mountain Lion from App Store and install. Then download Xcode 5 also from App Store and continue coding.

Comment: I never installed Mac OS. Is it dmg? Could it be installed just as general software?

Comment: Download from AppStore and follow the instructions that appear on screen.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, but could not nail down the exact approach to do this trick. Finally I gave up and installed Xcode 5 after upgrading the MacOSX. I use both Xcode 5 and 4 in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well, I fixed it by reopen Xcode. If not useful, you can try to clean your project and reopen again.